# How to assign an event as a condition in if statement (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a nav bar.
I want to check whether a `slideUp()` is applied on a `ul` or not with `if` statement and if it was applied then I want to apply `classToggle()` on `<span>` within the parent `li`

Html:

```
<li class="main"><span class="arrow-up"></span>
  <ul class="sub">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="main"><span class="arrow-up"></span>
  <ul class="sub">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I am using the following code to close the active submenu once another is clicked and to toggle `'arrow-up arrow-down'` classes but I want to toggle these classes only if the submenu is slided up  so I want to insert `.slideUp()` event in `if` statement , how to do that ?

```
$('.main').click(function(){
   $('ul',this).slideToggle('fast');

    // slide up the current active ul
    $('ul','.main').not($('ul',this)).slideUp('fast');

    $('span',this).toggleClass('arrow-up arrow-down');

    $('span','.main').not($('span',this)).toggleClass('arrow-up arrow-down');

    }
```

Comment: _"I want to check whether a slideToggle() is applied on a ul"_ Is requirement to check whether `ul` element is visible ? Can include `js` tried at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to the element when you use `.slideToggle()` on it and use that class to detect if element is toggled.

You could also use `if ( $('.element').is(':visible') ) { //Do something`

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly ? try utilizing `complete` callback of `.slideToggle()` , `.prev()` to select closest `span` element

```js
$(".main").click(function() {
  var complete = function complete() {
    $(this).prev("span").toggleClass("arrow-up arrow-down");
  };

  $("ul", this).slideToggle("fast", complete)
  .promise()
  .then(function() {
    var elems = $("ul", ".main").not(this);
    if (elems.is(":visible") && $(this).is(":visible")) {
        elems.slideToggle("fast", complete);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow-down {
  color: blue;
}
.arrow-up {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li class="main"><span class="arrow-up">span</span>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main"><span class="arrow-up">span</span>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```